# azcopy v10 copy doesn't copy blob metadata

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

We use blob metadata and are trying to copy large volume of blobs from one storage account to another. we see that blob is copied while the metadata is not.

We are using azcopy v10

Comment: have you tried `--s2s-preserve-properties` flag? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 12/17:**

The issue(when using `azcopy sync`, the metadata is not copied) is solved in [azcopy version 10.3.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#download-azcopy). I have tested it, it works in v10.3.3.

---

Please try to use the latest version of azcopy, [v10.3.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#download-azcopy), it works fine at my side:

The command to copy:

```
azcopy copy "https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/test1/js-appinsights.PNG?sasToken" "https://yy4.blob.core.windows.net/test1/3.PNG?sasToken"
```

The result:

[image]

**The source blob** with metadata:

[image]

**After copied**, the destination blob also has same metadata:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ivan-yang. We did use 10.3.2 but azcopy sync. azcopy sync "https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/test?sasToken" "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/test?sasToken"

Comment: @LakshmanaPrabhuVenkatesan, ok, I see. And I go through the source code of azcopy, and find that for "sync" command, the metadata is not specified, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/master/cmd/sync.go#L39) for details; But for "copy" command, the metadata is specified [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/master/cmd/copy.go#L62). So I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/748) for sync command, and will let you know if any feedback.

Comment: @LakshmanaPrabhuVenkatesan, the issue(azcopy sync) is solved in the version 10.3.3, you can download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#download-azcopy). I have tested it, the metadata can be copied with "azcopy sync" command.